# Inheriting the same method from multiple interfaces

Tags: c#, inheritance

That we know multiple (interface) inheritance is allow in c# but, I want to know is it possible that two interface 
Example :

```
 interface calc1
{
    int addsub(int a, int b);
}
interface calc2
{
    int addsub(int x, int y);
}
```

with same method name with same type and with same type of parameter

will get inherit in above class ?

```
class Calculation : calc1, calc2
{
    public int result1;
    public int addsub(int a, int b)
    {
        return result1 = a + b;
    }
    public int result2;
    public int addsub(int x, int y)
    {
        return result2= a - b;
    }
}
```

if yes then which interface method will get called.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In future, please follow naming conventions even for sample code - capitalized member names, interfaces beginning with `I` etc. It avoids a mental "huh?" when reading the code.

Comment: And its good to check in console application before asking coz VS itself let you know the error..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't overload the method like that, no - they have the same signatures. Your options are:

- Use *one* implementation, which will be called by both interfaces
- Use explicit interface implementation for one or both of the methods, e.g.

  ```
  int calc2.addsub(int x, int y)
  {
      return result2 = a - b;
  }
  ```

  If you do that for both methods, *neither* method will be callable on a reference of type `Calculation`; instead, you'd have to cast to one interface or the other before calling the method, including within the class. For example:

  ```
  public void ShowBoth()
  {
      Console.WriteLine(((calc1)this).addsub(5, 3)); // 8
      Console.WriteLine(((calc2)this).addsub(5, 3)); // 2
  }
  ```